# java, collection for known amount of enums

Tags: java, collections

what kind of collection should I use if:

1. I want to store max. 5 `Enums` in the collection
2. Reading, writing and iterating over collection can happen multiple
       times per second
3. If I will need to add new element then the oldest
       element will be removed (Assume it has `e1...e5` and when I add `e6` it will be
       `e2...e6`).

I will be almost always iterating over the whole collection. I guess `LinkedList` is what I need, but I'm not very experienced in `Java`, so I want to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html)

```
LinkedBlockingQueue lbq =new LinkedBlockingQueue(5);
if(!(lbq.offer(newOBject)){
  lbq.take();
  lbq.offer(newObject);
}
```

[EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) might also be useful, keys restricted to enum instances.

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is a Queue Data Structure which supports FIFO .

You can use LinkedList  from Collections Framework.It implements Queue Interface.

[Read more about Linked List in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

Answer (score 0):

**If you do not need to enforce the capacity of the queue** you can just use `LinkedList`. It implements `Queue` interface, which is what you actually need.

Use it like this:

```
Queue<EnumClass> queue = new LinkedList<EnumClass>();
queue.offer(newObj);
takenObj = queue.poll();
```

**If you have to limit the size** an `ArrayBlockingQueue` would be a good option, since there will be no additional internal object creation (collection backed by an array).

```
Queue<EnumClass> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<EnumClass>(capacity);
```

Still, using it with `Queue` interface would be a good idea. That way you can change the actual implementations at will.